# Finding a Child element of a closest div with a certain class upward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having elements as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="something">
        <div class="something-inner" data-id="xyz">
            some contents
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <a onclick="doSomething();"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

in function doSomething(), I need to get the data-id of div with "something-inner". I have tried using this code,

```
$(this).parent(".parent").find(".something-inner").data("id");
```

But it does not select the ".something-inner" div and get the data "xyz".

Comment: what is `this`? and whether it is done in the `doSomething()` method?

Comment: **Disclaimer: I am the author.** You might find this useful in this case: http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom - In this case, use it like `$(this).prevInDOM('.something-inner');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

Dom:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="something">
    <div class="something-inner" data-id="xyz">
        some contents
    </div>
</div>
<div class="next">
    <a onclick="doSomething(this);"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
function doSomething(obj){
alert($(obj).closest('.parent').find(".something-inner").data("id"););
}
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ehp/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="something">
            <div class="something-inner" data-id="xyz">
                some contents
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="next">
            <a onclick="doSomething(this);"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>

    function doSomething(obj)
    {
          console.log($(obj).parent().prev().find(".something-inner").attr("data-id"));
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically `.parent()` will select the element's immediate parent, You should use `.closest()` to achieve the result of your expectation.

Try,

HTML:

```
<a onclick="doSomething(e);"></a>
```

JS:

```
$(e).closest(".parent").find(".something-inner").data("id");
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

**html**

```
<a onclick="doSomething(this);"></a>
```

**javascript**

```
function doSomething(obj){
    $(obj).parent(".parent").find(".something-inner").data("id");
}
```